# getJSON is not retrieving json object

Tags: jquery, python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've a GAE app in python using Django. I'm trying to fetch a json from a python api using jquery's get / getJSON api but it doesn't read the passed string as json. Am I missing something here?

Django template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/test/api?request=getallwords', function(json) {
        $('body').append(json);
        var j = JSON.stringify(json)
        $.each(json.details,function(i){
            $('#list').append($('<li>' + this.word + '</li>'));
        });
        alert(j);
    });
    },'json');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```

And here's the python api.

```
words = Word.all().fetch(20)
for w in words:
   d = {"word":w.name.encode('utf-8'),"lists":[]}
   for l in w.word_lists:
      d["lists"].append({"list":l.word_list.name.encode('utf-8')})
success["details"].append(d)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/javascript'
self.response.out.write(success)
```

And the json example

> {'response': 'success', 'details': [{'word': 'mcity', 'lists': [{'list': 'infy'}, {'list': 'dasd'}]}, {'word': 'mcity_1', 'lists': []}, {'word': 'mcity_2', 'lists': []}, {'word': 'mydc', 'lists': [{'list': 'infy'}]}, {'word': 'hyddc', 'lists': [{'list': 'infy'}]}, {'word': 'abysmal', 'lists': [{'list': 'gre words'}]}, {'word': 'ascent', 'lists': [{'list': 'gre words'}, {'list': 'infy'}, {'list': 'mine'}]}, {'word': 'assda', 'lists': [{'list': 'dasd'}]}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/test/api?request=getallwords', function(json) {
        $('body').append(json);
        var j = JSON.stringify(json)
        $.each(json.details,function(i){
            $('#list').append($('<li>' + this.word + '</li>'));
        });
        alert(j);
    }); // error, you close the $('document').ready() here
    },'json');
```

should like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/test/api?request=getallwords', function(json) {
        $('body').append(json);
        var j = JSON.stringify(json)
        $.each(json.details,function(i){
            $('#list').append($('<li>' + this.word + '</li>'));
        });
        alert(j);
    },'json');
 });
```

Comment: This was actually one of the problem. I accidentally removed the `self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/javascript'` and also changed `self.response.out.write(success)` to `self.response.out.write(json.dumps(success))` and I got it displayed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using jQuery [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)() not `getJSON()` so you need to specific the `dataType` as JSON in the request object.

If you're thinking the 'json' below is doing this, I think you've got the closing parens mixed up (GET would close before the `$(document).ready()`

```
});
    },'json');
```